# Page has Scrolling even with no content in it

Tags: html, css

I have a simple `HTML` template and a relevant `CSS`.

I am getting scrolling by default on the page even it has no content in it.

Instead of posting code snippets, [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/aFvzL/) I am linking its [JsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aFvzL/)

Comment: Probably because you have `min-height: 100%;` in your `.container` while there is a footer & header also being displayed.

Comment: You change the min-height to something more suitable to your needs. I can't say exact amounts because it would be a height that suits your interests. You can play around with it, make it something like `550px`, just keep toying with it until you find the height that suits you.

Comment: I have set `html(height:100%;)`  and then everything should be resized inside `HTML`

Comment: @user3709682: (1) You should not have a 20px margin on body, make it on your menu. (2) Your menu and footer have their own heights, hence making container min-height as 100% will exceed the body height and hence scrollbars. Calculate the difference of heights of menu and footer for the container.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/aFvzL/2/

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have given height to body,html.

Try removing that and it will fix your problem.

Here is the updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/aFvzL/1/

```
html {
}
body {
    background:#fff;

    margin-top:20px;
}
```

Also if you want your container to get a particular min-height or device height, try assigning that with js. Your device height is $(window).height(). You can use this do other sub/add and set the container height by $('#containerid').height(calculatedHeight);

Comment: that is an incorrect answer. without explicit height on html/body the percent heights on container won't work.

Comment: Please have a look at the content ... its shrunk

Answer (score 0):

You need to research how to do a sticky footer. E.g. http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/sticky-footer-auto-height.htm

Everything except the footer should be inside the container. At the moment, you have various problems, such as

- the margin on the body element
- the header outside the container
- the border on the container element